# note app using aura framework not working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to run the note app using aura framework but when I fired the command ,

`mvn jetty:run -X`

I get the following error. How to resolve it,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project aura-note:
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.auraframework.demo:aura-note:
jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.auraframework:aura-util:jar:0.2841:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.auraframework:aura-util:jar:0.2841: 
Could not transfer artifact org.auraframework:aura-util:pom:0.2841 from/to libs-internal : 
maven.auraframework.org: unknown error: Unknown host maven.auraframework.org: unknown error -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: You might want to have a look @ https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura-note/issues/9

Comment: @Abhijeet I was looking at the same link but didn't get what to do exactly Can you please clarify it. I am new to AURA Framework just started to start learing it. Thanks in Advance